# OneToMany Bi-Directional Mapping to fetch data through Query in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm having OneToMany bi-directional mapping for Drama-Characters (One Drama with multiple Characters).

**Drama:**

dramaId

dramaName

characters (Character entity)

**Characters:**

characterId

firstName

lastName

drama (drama entity reference)

**Problem:**

How can i fetch the drama details with respect to Character.firstName through Query annotation in CharacterRepository.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could provide some code you tried. Whatever,

You can follow this for relation mapping [hibernate-one-to-many](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)
Then declare your repository both for Drama and Character entities.
Now, inside your Character-repo:
say like this:

```
@Repository
public interface CharacterRepository extends  extends JpaRepository<Character, Long>{
 Character getByFirstName(String firstName); //i am assuming firstName is unique
}
```

You just need to call this method now to get details of Character and associated Drama entities.